# reveal a clipped div

Tags: jquery, css

Based on the code below, I want to be able to hover over SubBlockA (or B) and have the clipped information that is currently hidden based on the size of the big block to reveal. More specifically, currently subBlockA is clipped at K, when I hover over subBlockA I would like to be able to reveal the rest of the text with out affect the rest of the structure. I'm not sure if this is possible with CSS, or if I need to do it tooltip style and have something appear over the DIV. Any suggestions

http://jsfiddle.net/randallmeeker/6bVmb/

```
<style>
div {
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bigBlock {
    width: 100px; 
}
.nowrap{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
​</style>
<div id="bigBlock">
    <div id="subBlockA" class="nowrap">ABCDEFGHIJKL MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
    <div id="subBlockB" class="nowrap">12345678901 234567890</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can do this very easily using css and `:hover`:

http://jsfiddle.net/6bVmb/1/

Comment: Note that if the browser doesn't support `:hover` the hidden part will always be hidden. The `a` tag has better hover support in that case, or it can always be done with a little js snippet.

Comment: The :hover selector is supported in all major browsers. In IE there must be declared a  <!DOCTYPE> for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the <a> element. Js is overkill for this in my opinion.

Comment: OP didn't specify "all major" browsers. Other than that I agree.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the fiddle what about this where the items are stacked next to each other. I tried messing witht the background color but it is clipped still. http://jsfiddle.net/randallmeeker/P6Bhz/

Comment: Problem with having them side by side is that you have to specify a width for clipping the text. When they are side by side they wont have the clearance needed to reveal the hidden text without overlapping with the next one. I would recommend having them one per line for this reason.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I can not. The Fiddle is a simple rep of a calender UI i'm working on where monday would be right next to tuesday and if monday's event it to large to fit in the cell, then I want it to display fully when hovered. I have acheived this with jQuery and a <div> that takes moves over the clipped div, but I was hopefully for a more gracefull approach and was a little excited  at the thought of doing this in pure CSS